# Could anyone tell me any plugin or how to create Notification in a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, bootstrapping

I am creating a web application and I want to include a **notification** box instead of a message box to show what the user is doing or any error message. So far I have found a plugin **lobibox** which provides **notification pop up** from the side and is removed automatically after a certain time or the user could remove it.

[image]

I would like to know is there anyway that i could create notification like instead of using a plugin? If not, is there any other plugin other than lobibox?

If you share a code, that would be much better. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend using https://github.com/tameraydin/ngToast.
Really easy to setup and configure.

Comment: Thanks.... For now i stick with lobibox plugin.. later I would use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several other notification plugins.

- [notifyme](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?koLHvt8W)
- [AmaranJS](https://github.com/hakanersu/AmaranJS)
- [jQuery Growl](https://github.com/zoul0813/jquery-growl)

The best that i have come across is [notifIt!](https://github.com/naoxink/notifIt)

You can find a whole lot more [here](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/notification-box)

Comment: Thanks for the help....!

Comment: @gayan1991 you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can create it yourself manually. Here's a dead simple way in which you can recreate that effect.

1.) On the RHS of the panel, create multiple DIVS. These will be your message box. Style them up nicely using CSS + Animations.

2.) Once you are satisfied with your design, add a css "hidden" class to it which will hide the DIVS

3.) When you want to show the "notification box", simply un-hide those divs and animate them in. Remember to set the notification box content with the text that you want too.

Comment: Hi, thanks. If you have something that you have actually built sample, that would be much better